# wrong number of arguments error while building a chainable ruby api

Tags: ruby, api-design, fluent-interface

In my gem I have a class called `Client` that I want to operate like this:

```
client = Client.new
client.content_type('pages').content_type
```

That means I want to set a property and then expect to immediately get it back in the same chain. This is what I have so far:

```
class Client
  attr_reader :content_type

  def initialize(options = {})
    @options = options
  end

  def content_type
    @content_type
  end

  def content_type(type_id)
    @content_type = type_id
    self
  end
end
```

Now when I try to run `client.content_type('pages').content_type` I get:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from chaining.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I write this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The names of your methods are conflicting. The second method is overriding the first. Either use different names or consolidate to do both like:

```
class Client
  attr_reader :content_type

  def initialize(options = {})
    @options = options
  end

  def content_type(type_id = nil)
    if type_id
      @content_type = type_id
      self
    else
      @content_type
    end
  end
end
```

Btw, this code stinks because the returned values for this are of different type depending on how it's called. You shouldn't do it unless you have a good reason to.

Comment: Could you perhaps help me with improving the code design? What would a better design look like?

Comment: @Amit I suggest that `content_type` should be `attr_accessor` of your class, so you could do `client.content_type = "pages"` or `client.content_type # output "pages"`.